# Registration where both MappedToType and InjectionFactory are set is not supported

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I have ASP.NET MVC application. It was using .NET 4.5.1 with below Unity versions

```
<package id="Unity" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="Unity.Mvc" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
```

This is how i was registering DBContext

```
     container.RegisterType<DbContext, MyDBContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager(), new InjectionFactory(x => CreateDBContext()));

     private static MyDbContext CreateDBContext()
    {
        MyDbContext dbContext = new MyDbContext ();
        dbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;// turn-off loading on-demand
        dbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;// turn-off dynamic proxy class generation
        return dbContext;
    }
```

this has been working fine.
Now i updated .NET Framework to 4.6.2 and also Unity versions to

```
<package id="Unity" version="5.8.5" targetFramework="net462" />
<package id="Unity.Abstractions" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
<package id="Unity.Container" version="5.8.5" targetFramework="net462" />
<package id="Unity.Mvc" version="5.0.13" targetFramework="net462" />
```

However doing so throws exception on application startup during the DBContext registration

> Registration where both MappedToType and InjectionFactory are set is
>   not supported

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When using an InjectionFactory, you should not set the explicit type to instantiate in `RegisterType`.

This should work:

```
container.RegisterType<DbContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager(), new InjectionFactory(x => CreateDBContext()));
```

You are delegating the job of instantiating the object to a custom factory, therefore the container does not need to know the type to instantiate.